# Outlook and Calendar stopped working

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calendars, outlook, blu-win-hd

Suddenly yesterday Outlook and Calendar stopped working. All other app are working fine (including Word, Excel).

When I press button it appears and the disappeares itself.

Is it problem with my phone or Microsoft's services?

Should I do hard reset or wait?

PS. It started working. Does it mean that is was problem with Microsoft services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wife had this happen to her, shortly after an update. After a day or so it started working again. I wouldn't do a hard reset. Maybe a soft reset tho if it still persists.

Also, you can try Wifi vs Cell signal.

Comment: yes, it started working next way